# Semantic UI - what is status of Font Awesome licence?

Tags: semantic-ui

Semantic-UI is released under an MIT licence.

However it is documented as including Font-Awesome

> Semantic includes a complete port of Font Awesome 5.0.8 designed by
>   the FontAwesome team for its standard icon set.

and as far as understand the Font-Awesome documentation, it is not released under the MIT licence, if one wants to host Font-Awesome one needs the Pro licence.

What, if any, limitations apply to my use of Font-awesome in my product, in a purely self-hosted environment?

Comment: As instructed on the "how to host yourself" page referenced by Guilherme I have downloaded the Free version, and it includes the licence text referenced below. My conclusion: self-hosting is covered by the Free Licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a pro license to host the free version of Font Awesome. They even teach you [how to host it yourself](https://fontawesome.com/v5.0.13/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself).

About the limitations, as seen on the [Font Awesome Free's license](https://fontawesome.com/license/free), the only thing you can't do is:

> Use the Font Awesome name in the name of your project.

Answer (score 1):

The [Font Awesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/license/free) state:

> Font Awesome Free is free, open source, and GPL friendly. You can use it for commercial projects, open source projects, or really almost whatever you want.
>
> Attribution is required by MIT, SIL OFL, and CC BY licenses. Downloaded Font Awesome Free files already contain embedded comments with sufficient attribution, so you shouldn't need to do anything additional when using these files normally.

I would assume Semantic UI follows the above guidelines.